# Can Sentry catch network error (XHR or fetch) in browser?

Tags: sentry

I am currently integrating Sentry into an Angular web application.
I am successfully reporting console.log / warn / error and exceptions in Sentry as "issue".

However, when a request to my server fails (HTTP 4XX or 5XX), Sentry totally ignores this error and does not send it.

I have tried all possible values for `tracingOrigins`.

```js
Sentry.init({
    dsn: '******',
    integrations: [
        new CaptureConsole(),
        new Integrations.BrowserTracing({
            tracingOrigins: ['localhost', 'http://localhost:4646/api']
        })
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
    debug: true
});
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `HttpClient` from `@sentry/integrations` to handle that. See reference [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/integrations/plugin/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F#httpclient). This was introduced in `7.30.0`.

```js
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser";
import { HttpClient as HttpClientIntegration } from "@sentry/integrations";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "YOUR_SENTRY_DSN",
  integrations: [
    new HttpClientIntegration({
      // This array can contain tuples of `[begin, end]` (both inclusive),
      // single status codes, or a combination of both.
      // default: [[500, 599]]
      failedRequestStatusCodes: [[500, 505], 507],

      // This array can contain Regexes, strings, or a combination of both.
      // default: [/.*/]
      failedRequestTargets: [
        "http://example.com/api/test",
        /(staging\.)?mypage\.com/,
      ],
    }),
  ],

  // This option is required for capturing headers and cookies.
  sendDefaultPii: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unhandled rejection event found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event

When your promises fail and error out, but are uncaught, this event will fire. Here you can add Sentry.captureException.

However the fact that you have CaptureConsole means you are likely sending all console errors as sentry events, and uncaught 4xx and 5xx should be sent. I assume you are catching and handling these then?

One way to handle these is add Sentry.captureException in your fetch/xhr library when it processes the response object.

If its easier to just log every uncaught error, you can patch the Promise object:

```js
window.Promise = class extends Promise {
  catch(func, ...args) {
    let loggingFunc = (error = {}, ...args) => {
      console.warn('Promise caught', error);
      Sentry.breadcrumb('Promise caught', error.message, Sentry.Severity.Error);
      return func(error, ...args);
    };
    return super.catch(loggingFunc, ...args);
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd want an instance of Sentry running on your server to capture backend errors. You'd probably want to set these up in Sentry as two different projects.

Alternatively, you could manually track them in your Angular app when you get the response back - something like `Sentry.captureException(err);`

Comment: I will probably install a 2nd instance of Sentry for the backend as you say.

Sure I can change my code to add in Angular app `Sentry.captureException(err);`. But it will not work for errors downloading resources like fonts, favicon, images.

Thanks for your answer !